# vscode deselect one from "change all occurrences"

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode working in a file, and you need to change multiple variable etc.

When selecting all occurrences in a file, 
I often find that I need to de-select one or more, 
can you do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Mac, to **de-select** one or more substrings selected with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, type <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

Analogously, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> on Windows/Linux.

Found on https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/8gx98z/how_cancel_last_ctrld_selection/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use `Ctrl+D` to select multiple variables, press `K` while still holding `Ctrl` to skip/exclude the current selection.

Comment: Thanks, I use right-click/select all occurrences. But I can use (one a Mac) Command + D to select step by step, but same problem de-selecting one specific selection. Maybe it is not implemented.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your multi-cursor add command to also **de-select** specific cursors.  So if you have this setting:

> Editor: Multi Cursor Modifier
>
> The modifier to be used to add multiple cursors with the mouse. The Go
>   To Definition and Open Link mouse gestures will adapt such that they
>   do not conflict with the multicursor modifier. Read more.

set to `alt` (the default)  then you can <kbd>alt</kbd>+`left-mouse-click` them in any order to deselect them.  Or same with `Ctrl/Cmd` if that is your setting option.

If you use the find widget to find all your occurrences (select a word and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) then <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> will select them all from the start.  Then you can deselect any of them with the <kbd>alt</kbd>+`left-mouse-click` thing.  and then if you want them all reselected for any reason <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> will do that.

See demo for both methods (right-click vs find widget).

[image: demo of deslecting selections]